# React router not showing basic web page?

Tags: reactjs

This is my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Routes, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route } from "react-router";
import Home from "./react.components/Home/Home";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" component={<Home />} exact />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my Home.js from import Home from './react.components/Home/Home'

```
import React from "react";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <h2>hello world</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Yet when I go on localhost:3000 (where my react server is run) I see an empty page. I'm expecting to say Test and hello world?

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you look at the browser console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: no errors just white screen

Comment: The *console*, not the page

Comment: no errors https://gyazo.com/5937b9ead46fd6435437efd05a9cf114

Comment: That's not your browser console.

Comment: full warning: https://gyazo.com/67e891f9684cba6ca1ce50c39eeeaea5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your using `react-router-dom` v6. So you can reference this guide [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)

```js
// v4 and v5 before 5.1
<Route path="/" component={<Home />} exact />

// v6
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

this syntax is not correct

```
<Route path="/" component={<Home />} exact />
```

instead try this

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} exact />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).